# Is there any way to create message/(inbox mail) with specific date (i.e create/sentDateTime/updateDateTime) using Graph/ office REST API?

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Trying convert old SOAP message created by EWS to modern Graph API , Previously I succeed to create a message with specific dates due to sending MimeConent which already includes with dates Example:

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
               <soap:Header>
                  <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2016" />
                  <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
                     <t:ConnectingSID>
                        <t:PrincipalName>admin@xxx.com</t:PrincipalName>
                     </t:ConnectingSID>
                  </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
               </soap:Header>
               <soap:Body>
                  <CreateItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" MessageDisposition="SaveOnly" SendMeetingInvitations="SendToNone">

                     <SavedItemFolderId>
                        <t:FolderId Id="AAMkAGM5MDIzODk0LTg2NmMtNDE3YS05M2YwLTBhZjgzZWQxODUxYQAuAAAAAAAX07OCLT/gQbX2qJJIVqojAQCdUXzQSXe1Tqh1KvhfGj3SAARQNYfhAAA=" ChangeKey="AQAAABYAAACdUXzQSXe1Tqh1KvhfGj3SAARSy240" />
                     </SavedItemFolderId>
                     <Items>
                        <t:Message>

                  //here MimeContent that has the specific dates....how to 
                       do that with REST ??????

                          <t:MimeContent CharacterSet="UTF-8">

  ......{BASE 64 ........} </t:MimeContent>

                           <t:ReminderIsSet>false</t:ReminderIsSet>
                           <t:ExtendedProperty>
                              <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="0x0E07" PropertyType="Integer" />
                              <t:Value>4</t:Value>
                           </t:ExtendedProperty>
                        </t:Message>
                     </Items>
                  </CreateItem>
               </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>
```

if I'll decode the MimeContent with base64 , will get the result as describes , and this creates me the specific "dates" such as: createTime...

```
Date: Thu, 22 Jun 2017 11:36:01 +0000 (UTC)
From: valekseev@zzzzz.com
To: xxx@yyyy.zzzzz.com
Message-ID: <CAP-g2LzDoXpYeP+7PPs3LJYQtTkPe9ErqD-SgnbHKYZkkw5YuA@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: Test OutOfMemory
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; 
    boundary="----=_Part_0_1169672575.1519724417079"

------=_Part_0_1169672575.1519724417079
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div dir="ltr">Test OutOfMemory<br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I'm Trying to do the same with REST API (the value are different, but it doesn't matter):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages
    Content-type: application/json

    {
        "subject":"Did you see last night's game?",
        "importance":"Low",
        "sentDateTime":"2016-12-23T07:29:58Z",
        "body":{
            "contentType":"HTML",
            "content":"They were <b>awesome</b>!"
        },
        "toRecipients":[
            {
                "emailAddress":{
                    "address":"AdeleV@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            }
        ]

    , "singleValueExtendedProperties": [
          {
             "id":"Integer 0x0E07",
             "value":"4"
          }
        ]
     }
    }
```

BUT I The message that I got always with `sentDateTime` of "now"... why?

Maybe is there an option to create message with my "content" instead of body...

OUTPUT:

```
    "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('ad787b4f-1fda-4523-8e48-ffedb7f4635f')/messages/$entity",
    "@odata.etag":"W/\"CQAAABYAAAAmXr9SsE/UR4PcnTZcg7qWAAAFS12t\"",
    "id":"AAMkAGRWAAAFSmKXAAA=",

     // I want here to be "2016-12-23T07:29:58Z" 
    "createdDateTime":"2018-03-02T19:14:13Z",  
    "lastModifiedDateTime":"2018-03-02T19:14:13Z",
    "changeKey":"CQAAABYAAAAmXr9SsE/UR4PcnTZcg7qWAAAFS12t",
    "categories":[

    ],
    "receivedDateTime": "2018-03-02T19:14:13Z",
    "sentDateTime": "2018-03-02T19:14:13Z",
    "hasAttachments":false,
    "internetMessageId":"<MWHPR130@MWHPR130.namprd13.prod.outlook.com>",
    "subject":"Did you see last night's game?".....,....
     ......
     ......
```

Is it possible to create a message with specific creation date like i did with EWS before...Maybe some MAPI Properties like :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765677.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Rest API today doesn't support inserting Mime content or thereof the ability to create a message with mime content. Please send in your suggestions or up vote an existing suggestion here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com

Comment: @Yogesh , Is there any other way to set "create" /"update" date...I saw some MAPI Tag properties like , PR_CREATE_TIME , and other more....Maybe, Can it help ??? like : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765677.aspx

Comment: Don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope.  You can't do that.  Store/Transport stamps the dates on the items when the items are created and delivered.  For many reasons it is good to keep this field accurate, such as legal hold/compliance, etc...

Comment: @ David Sterling - MSFT, Hi ..I've edited my question to be more specific....please , review it again if you can :)

Comment: MimeContent in EWS is a pretty close to "full fidelity" representation of a message, and you are right, EWS supports it.  The REST API doesn't currently support MIME, though it may in the future.  The reason we have been hesitant about MIME support is that MIME processing is actually pretty expensive.  This is because Exchange doesn't store messages as MIME, but stores something we call a MIME "skeleton", and so converting back to MIME requires putting flesh on that skeleton :).  So, currently there is no way that I know of to overwrite those properties via REST.

Comment: Thanks for your answers...what about all MAPI Properties ..I saw Tags like : PR_CREATE_TIME , etc'... they can't help , what they are used for ?

Comment: Yes, those are all MAPI properties, but not all MAPI properties are settable.  CreateTime, ReceivedTime, etc... are great for fetching and allowing you to present a message list sorted by received date for instance.

Answer (score 1):

`PR_CREATION_TIME` and `PR_LAST_MODIFICATION_TIME` MAPI properties cannot be modified but for some reason `PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME` and `PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME` can be modified.
Doing it will update `sentDateTime` and `receivedDateTime` accordingly.