# Graph API doesn't restore a mail message, instead it is creating a new message with CreateDateTime automatically updated to present date

Tags: api, graph

When I am performing restore of an email message via graph API with a Post request, instead of restoring it is creating a new message with the same data. Because in the JSON createDateTime is being updated although I am passing previous createDataTime.

To elaborate more: I want to restore below mail message which got created in 2018 ( "createdDateTime": "2018-12-31T14:49:42Z") but when I am posting same JSON for restore, createDateTime is being updated automatically to the present date. Which is problem because it's not the restore, it is just like creating new message.

```
{
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.eventMessageResponse",
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"DAAAABYAAABjFtMyIejaSbuRSeM/auJwAAGfpJnO\"",
            "id": "AAMkAGZiNGI0MWM4LTQ0NjUtNDUyMy1hOTI2LWNopaTZiMGYxZTBkNQBGAAAAAACaBIVNrajXSj6AQcjiAFBwBjFtMyIejaSbuRSeM-auJwAAAAAAEJAABjFtMyIejaSbuRSeM-auJwAAGf4eRfAAA=",
            "createdDateTime": "2018-12-31T14:49:42Z",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-12-31T14:49:46Z",
            "changeKey": "DopskAkslaAABjFtMyIejaSbuRSeM/auJwAAGfpJnO",
            "categories": [],
            "receivedDateTime": "2020-12-31T14:49:43Z",
            "sentDateTime": "2020-12-31T14:49:42Z",
            "hasAttachments": false,
            "internetMessageId": "<MA1PR0101MB207oPF15907003958DB7A58BDD60@MA1PR0101MB2070.INDPRD01.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM>",
            "subject": "Accepted: New Year Party",
            "bodyPreview": "",
            "importance": "normal",
            "parentFolderId": "AQMkAGZiNGI0MWM4LTQ0ADY1LTQ1MjMtYTkyNi1jZGU2YjBmMWUwZDUALgAAA5oEhU2tqNdKuqPoBByOIAlkallspspspspspppAAAIBCQAAAA==",
            "conversationId": "AAQkAGZiNGI0MWM4LTQ0NjUtNDUyMy1hOTI2LWNkZTZiMGYxZTBkNQAQAEJ5AU8Tk1nklXE3E0XGh2w=",
            "conversationIndex": "AQHW34QsrZ0Wy3deoU2Bn2byefNABQ==",
            "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": null,
            "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
            "isRead": true,
            "isDraft": false,
            "inferenceClassification": "focused",
            "meetingMessageType": "meetingAccepted",
            "type": "singleInstance",
            "isOutOfDate": false,
            "isAllDay": false,
            "isDelegated": false,
            "responseType": "accepted",
            "recurrence": null,
            "body": {
                "contentType": "text",
                "content": ""
            },
            "sender": {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Mark Rober",
                    "address": "mark@securemigration.in"
                }
            },
            "from": {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "Mark Rober",
                    "address": "mark@securemigration.in"
                }
            },
            "toRecipients": [
                {
                    "emailAddress": {
                        "name": "#Class Yammer",
                        "address": "ClassYammer@securemigration.in"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "ccRecipients": [],
            "bccRecipients": [],
            "replyTo": [],
            "flag": {
                "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
            },
            "startDateTime": {
                "dateTime": "2020-12-31T15:00:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            },
            "endDateTime": {
                "dateTime": "2020-12-31T15:30:00.0000000",
                "timeZone": "UTC"
            }
        }
```

Please help me with it.

Comment: Did you find a way to set the original dates?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076081/is-there-any-way-to-create-message-inbox-mail-with-specific-date-i-e-create-s/49076261

Comment: Although, I am able to restore email using Graph API successfully still Datetime is not uneditable. For that, I am using EWS API. If anyone is working on a Javascript project and wants this, I would highly recommend ews-javascript-api npm written by Gautam.